# Is there a way to tell the supported input formats of libmap.dll without the associated .exe?

Tags: gdal, mapserver, mapscript

I have only compiled Mapscript_csharp and supporting dlls used in a .NET application - not the executables. Is there a way to tell what input / output formats are supported by these dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just do this: osgeo.MapServer.mapscript.msGetVersion